# If a node Z in a conditional probability query P(X|capY) is not requisite, how do we know that there exist networks where P(X|Y) are not equal?

Tags: probability, self-study, graphical-model, bayesian-network

I'm mostly confused about the second part. Can somebody generate a constructive proof here?
[image: Question]

Comment: Use the self study tag.

Comment: Done. Let me know if you have any helpful hints for the second bullet point.